# Can somebody please tell me where the error is in my regex line?

Tags: javascript, regex

I've figured out this pattern:

```
(?<=module.exports = function routes\(\) {\n)[\S\s]*?(?=\n})
```

to select the text inside the curly braces in this text:

```
module.exports = function routes() {
  this.root('pages#main');
  this.get('/dashboard', 'pages#dashboard');
}
```

Will somebody please teach me why this is invalid?:

```
myVar = data.match(/(?<=module.exports \= function routes\(\) {\n)[\S\s]*?(?=\n})/);
```

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: Why are you using regular expressions to parse JavaScript code? Why not use JavaScript to parse JavaScript code? require the module. the module.exports.toString and tada, you have the text. Isn't that simpler?

Comment: I tried your suggestion and I still get function routes() { at the beginning, so it looks like I would still need to use a regular expression to get only the contents into an array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if `toString()` works in your context then this should work also

```
var str = module.exports.toString();
str = str.replace(/function [^ ]+\(\)\s*\{/, '').replace(/\}$/,'');
```

Comment: Thanks!  That got me going in the right direction:

    data = data.replace(/((.|\n)*?)module(.|\n)exports(.|\n)+{/m, '').replace(/\}$/,'');
   data = data.split(';');